# Openni_launch for Ubuntu ARM

Tags: openni, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all
I see the status of building ROS hydro for ARM in this website [link text](http://packages.namniart.com/repos/status/hydro.html) , and I have some confusion.

With HbinParmhf 692 717  , the openni_launch missing , but with HbinParmhf 704 and 728 it has, so what is difference between them? I use Ubuntu 12.04 in my ARM board, so HbinParmhf 704 and 728 is for Ubuntu 13.04 is this right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132036/openni_launch-for-ubuntu-arm/) by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2014-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The three columns on the status page are building, shadow and public respectively, and the numbers at the top of each column represent the number of packages in that column.

HbinParmhf stands for Hydro Binary Precise armhf (12.04)
HbinQarmhf stands for Hydro Binary Quantal armhf (12.10)
HbinRarmhf stands for Hydro Binary Raring armhf (13.04)

This means that the openni_launch package has built for Raring (13.04) but not for the other ubuntu versions.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0